# How do I change the date time output for a column

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I apologize for the simple question, but I'm fairly new to using MS SQL in the 'real world' and having trouble with date/time.  I have not been seen my question in the forums

My task is to convert Oracle queries to MS SQL queries.  There is a column in my table called 'updatedtm' that is formatted 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:ss:mmm' and I need to change the output to format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ss:mm'

this is the Oracle part of the query that does that:

```
select p.PERSONNUM, 
   p.fullnm as personfullname, 
   replace(t.shortnm,'_',' ') as license, 
   **to_char(s.updatedtm,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as updatedtm**
```

I've been working with CONVERT and can convert today's date to that format, but how do I get the column in my output for the updatedtm column!

Help, I've spent way too much time searching on this..

Comment: *"There is a column in my table called 'updatedtm' that is formatted 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:ss:mmm' and I need to change the output to format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ss:mm'"* date and time data types don't have a format. If your data is *stored* as a formatted string, it is, by definition, not a date and time and your design is flawed. You should fix the design and make the column a date and time data type. Formatting is for the presentation layer, not the RDBMS. How you do that, however, is application specific.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is format the time as you described, you can try the FORMAT() function.

For example, try,

SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss') as updatedtm